# Getting Last4 Digits of Card using Customer Object - Stripe API with PHP

Tags: php, stripe-payments

I want to get the last 4 digits of a customers card using Stripe. 
I have already stored the Customer using:

```
      // Get the credit card details submitted by the form
      $token = $_POST['stripeToken'];

      // Create a Customer
      $StripeCustomer = \Stripe\Customer::create(array(
              "description" => "$username",
              "card" => $token
      ));
```

Now I'd like to access and then store the card's last 4 digits. (For context, I want to show users which card they have stored using Stripe for future payments - this is not a subscription service).

I have searched for a solution but a lot of the posts are saving the last4 digits AFTER a charge, and pull the information from the charge like:

```
$last4 = null;
try {
    $charge = Stripe_Charge::create(array(
    "amount" => $grandTotal, // amount in cents, again
    "currency" => "usd",
    "card" => $token,
    "description" => "Candy Kingdom Order")
);
$last4 = $charge->card->last4;
```

I would like to do the same BEFORE the charge , so I want to pull the last 4 from the Customer Object. The Stripe API documentation shows the attribute path for last4 from Customers,
 `customer->sources->data->last4`

However, this does not seem to give me the correct last 4 digits.
`$last4 = $StripeCustomer->sources->data->last4;`

I think I am misunderstanding how to use attributes in the Stripe API. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

$last4 = $StripeCustomer->sources->data[0]->last4;

sources->data is an array so you'd have to select the first card.

Side note: You're using the token twice, once to create the customer, and the second to create the charge, this will result in an error as the token can only be used once. You'd have to charge the customer instead of the token.

Comment: Worked like a charm! 

Also to your side note: you are absolutely correct. That second piece of code that uses token to make the charge is pulled from another post. My code does in fact charge the customer object. Thanks again!

Comment: Thanks! The documentation was so unclear about that, it was giving some weird method that I suspect was making a second call, this is much better! :)

Comment: Thanks Matthew. Helped me out as well.

Comment: What about `default_source`?

Comment: `default_source` is a string containting the `ID of the default payment source for the customer.` so you would need another call to get the source object and read the `last4` from there.

Comment: As of version 2020-08-27, this doesn't work. Do we know how to get the last4 when creating the customer with the new version?

Comment: As of version 2020-08-27 the correct way to do this is via the https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list

Answer (score 4):

For any one else who lands here from search engines, here's a link to the Stripe docs on how to get the last 4 digits of a card saved to the customer https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/object#customer_object-sources-data-last4

Answer (score 1):

This API has changed since this was first answered. For API version 2020-08-27 you need to use the [`ListPaymentsMethod` API on the Customer object](https://stripe.com/docs/api/payment_methods/list?lang=php).

The path to access via JSON would look like this

```php
$paymentMethods = $stripe->paymentMethods->all([
  'customer' => 'cus_123',
  'type' => 'card',
]);
$last4 = $paymentMethods->data[0]->card->last4
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Laravel Cashier, this code will be helpful for you.

```
$data = User::find(auth()->user()->id);
$payment = $data->defaultPaymentMethod();
$last4 = $payment->last4;
$brand = $payment->brand;
dd($payment);
```

You can get all information from this object.