# re: getting last 4 digits from a bank account or card

Tags: php

I'm trying to connect through stripe object and derive the destination account, and then try and retrieve the customer object id, and eventually the available payment methods with the attached last 4 digits of either the bank account or card associated with the customer id.

```
  require_once 'stripe-php-master/init.php';   
  $stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
   $STRIPE_API_KEY
  );

  $link = $stripe->accounts->retrieve(
  $STRIPE_DEST
  []
   );

 $paymentMethods = $stripe->paymentMethods->all([
 'customer' => $customer,
  'type' => 'card',
 ]);

 $last4 = $paymentMethods->sources->data[0]->last4;
```

Answer (score 0):

For stripe, you may use retrieveSource

$stripe->customers->retrieveSource

So in PHP it is like

```
$stripe = new \Stripe\StripeClient(
  'sk_test_4eC39HqLyjWDarjtT1zdp7dc'
);
$stripe->customers->retrieveSource(
  'cus_8eqdcH07DUqA5s',
  'card_1LsEJ12eZvKYlo2C4AdGdib2',
  []
);
```

The response will be like

```
{
  "id": "card_1LsEJ12eZvKYlo2C4AdGdib2",
  "object": "card",
  "address_city": null,
  "address_country": null,
  "address_line1": null,
  "address_line1_check": null,
  "address_line2": null,
  "address_state": null,
  "address_zip": null,
  "address_zip_check": null,
  "brand": "Visa",
  "country": "US",
  "customer": "cus_8eqdcH07DUqA5s",
  "cvc_check": "pass",
  "dynamic_last4": null,
  "exp_month": 8,
  "exp_year": 2023,
  "fingerprint": "Xt5EWLLDS7FJjR1c",
  "funding": "credit",
  "last4": "4242",
  "metadata": {},
  "name": null,
  "redaction": null,
  "tokenization_method": null
}
```

So you parse it and the "last4" data item should be what you want

If you need further details, please refer to the official documentation:
https://stripe.com/docs/api/cards/retrieve

Further/other reference

[Getting Last4 Digits of Card using Customer Object - Stripe API with PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30447026/getting-last4-digits-of-card-using-customer-object-stripe-api-with-php)

Comment: Is there anyway to receive the card last4 by just using the account id, instead of the customer id?

Comment: please check "further/other reference" link in my answer and see whether it can provide the necessary information for you. Thanks